# Get matrix of handwritten digit in HTML canvas with javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to get the matrix of an object drawn on a canvas. I have a 500*500 canvas which needs to be converted to 28*28 to facilite compatibility with the MNIST dataset. 
However, when I try to print the matrix in the console, I only get zeros:

> [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.....]

Here's my code:

```js
var c = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d')
var paint = false
var hidden = false
window.onmousedown = toggle
window.onmousemove = draw
window.onmouseup = drawoff

function toggle() {
  if (paint) {
    paint = false;
  } else {
    paint = true;
  }
}

function draw(e) {
  var rect = c.getBoundingClientRect();
  if (paint && !hidden) ctx.fillRect(e.x - rect.left, e.y - rect.top, 50, 50)
}

function drawoff() {
  paint = false;
}

function clear() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
}

window.save = function() {
  var digit = new Image();
  digit.src = c.toDataURL();
  c.width = 28
  c.height = 28
  ctx.drawImage(digit, 4, 4, 20, 20);
  document.getElementById('img').src = c.toDataURL();
  // document.getElementById('c').style.display = 'none';
  hidden = true

  var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 28, 28);
  var imgBlack = []
  for (var i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) {
    if (imgData.data[i + 3] === 255) imgBlack.push(1)
    else imgBlack.push(0)
  }

  var dataStr = JSON.stringify(imgData)
  console.log(dataStr)
}
```

```css
canvas { border: solid 1px black }
```

```html
<div class="row canvas-button-css">
  <button class="btn btn-success" id="save" onclick="save()">Generate Image</button>
  <button class="btn btn-warning" id="clear" onclick="clear()">Clear Canvas</button>
</div>
<div class="row canvas-row-css">
  <img id="img" style="">
  <canvas id='c' class="canvas-css" width='500' height='500'></canvas>
</div>
```

(Or here on [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pzetor8h/))

PS: In the save function, the `imgData` matrix is also zeros, so it is not a problem with the conversion to `imgBlack`. Any help would be appreciated on how to properly get the image data onto the `imgData` matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a canvas as image. I'm using a buffer canvas (unattached to the DOM) `c1` to draw the image from the `c` canvas:

```js
  let c1 = document.createElement("canvas");
  let ctx1 = c1.getContext('2d')
  c1.width = 28
  c1.height = 28
  ctx1.drawImage(c, 4, 4, 20, 20);// c is the first canvas
```

The `c1` canvas is 28/28.

```js
var c = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d')
var paint = false
var hidden = false
window.onmousedown = toggle
window.onmousemove = draw
window.onmouseup = drawoff

function toggle() {
  if (paint) {
    paint = false;
  } else {
    paint = true;
  }
}

function draw(e) {
  var rect = c.getBoundingClientRect();
  if (paint && !hidden) ctx.fillRect(e.x - rect.left, e.y - rect.top, 50, 50)
}

function drawoff() {
  paint = false;
}

function clear() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
}

window.save = function() {

  
  let c1 = document.createElement("canvas");
  let ctx1 = c1.getContext('2d')
  c1.width = 28
  c1.height = 28
  ctx1.drawImage(c, 4, 4, 20, 20);
  document.getElementById('img').src = c1.toDataURL();
  // document.getElementById('c').style.display = 'none';
  hidden = true

  var imgData = ctx1.getImageData(0, 0, 28, 28);
  var imgBlack = []
  for (var i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) {
    if (imgData.data[i + 3] === 255) imgBlack.push(1)
    else imgBlack.push(0)
  }

  var dataStr = JSON.stringify(imgData)
  console.log(dataStr)
}
```

```css
canvas { border: solid 1px black }
```

```html
<div class="row canvas-button-css">
  <button class="btn btn-success" id="save" onclick="save()">Generate Image</button>
  <button class="btn btn-warning" id="clear" onclick="clear()">Clear Canvas</button>
</div>
<div class="row canvas-row-css">
  <img id="img" style="">
  <hr>
  <canvas id='c' class="canvas-css" width='500' height='500'></canvas>
</div>
```